# Error while installing NS2 on Ubuntu 17.01

Tags: ns2

The following error keeps appearing while installing ns2 on Ubuntu 17.01:

```
mdart/mdart_adp.cc: In member function ‘void ADP::sendDarq(nsaddr_t, 
int)’:
mdart/mdart_adp.cc:108:21: error: reference to ‘hash’ is ambiguous
nsaddr_t dstAdd_ = hash(reqId);
                 ^~~~
In file included from ./mdart/mdart.h:52:0,
             from ./mdart/mdart_adp.h:51,
             from mdart/mdart_adp.cc:47:
./mdart/mdart_function.h:230:17: note: candidates are: nsaddr_t 
 hash(nsaddr_t)
 inline nsaddr_t hash(nsaddr_t id) {
             ^~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:6575:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
             from /usr/include/c++/7/bitset:47,
             from ./mdart/mdart_function.h:62,
             from ./mdart/mdart.h:52,
             from ./mdart/mdart_adp.h:51,
             from mdart/mdart_adp.cc:47:
 /usr/include/c++/7/bits/functional_hash.h:58:12: note:                 
 template<class _Tp> struct std::hash
 struct hash;
        ^~~~
mdart/mdart_adp.cc: In member function ‘void ADP::sendDaup()’:
mdart/mdart_adp.cc:396:21: error: reference to ‘hash’ is ambiguous
nsaddr_t dstAdd_ = hash(mdart_->id_);
                 ^~~~
In file included from ./mdart/mdart.h:52:0,
             from ./mdart/mdart_adp.h:51,
             from mdart/mdart_adp.cc:47:
./mdart/mdart_function.h:230:17: note: candidates are: nsaddr_t 
hash(nsaddr_t)
 inline nsaddr_t hash(nsaddr_t id) {
             ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:6575:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
             from /usr/include/c++/7/bitset:47,
             from ./mdart/mdart_function.h:62,
             from ./mdart/mdart.h:52,
             from ./mdart/mdart_adp.h:51,
             from mdart/mdart_adp.cc:47:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/functional_hash.h:58:12: note:                 
template<class _Tp> struct std::hash
 struct hash;
        ^~~~
Makefile:93: recipe for target "mdart/mdart_adp.o" failed
make: *** [mdart/mdart_adp.o] Errore 1
Ns make failed!
See http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-problems.html for problems
```

Comment: Please add more information. Are you compiling from source code? What commands did you run? And 17.01 is not a version. Do you mean 17.04?

Comment: I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04. I've checked now that the 17.10 it's a LTS version. Maybe that could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

'ns-2.35' Ubuntu 17.10 : `sudo apt install g++-5` → I.e. no later than g++-5 (>=5.4) can be used. **Note** : You can have as many gcc versions as you want, installed at the same time.

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz           // 2014 - 2017 update
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
export CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 && ./install
cd ns-2.35/
sudo make install
```

If you want additional protocols → All ~300 patches → https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2lWZDBRSW40Q00?usp=sharing ... And ~2500 simulations https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing